# Django form.is_valid() is always False while uploading images

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

## views.py

I am trying to upload an image but form.is_valid always return false

```
def  upload(request):

    if request.method=="POST":

        form=uploadform(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd=cleaned_data
            form.save(commit=True)
            return render(request,"success.html")
        else:
            form=uploadform()
            return render(request,'pico.html',{'form':form})
```

here is the form

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
         {{form.as_p}}
         {% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

## forms.py

```
class uploadform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=examplemodel
        fields=['pic']
```

## models.py

```
class examplemodel(models.Model):
    pic=models.ImageField()
```

Comment: What are the errors on the form?

Comment: i have edited the question... it does not show any error but form.is_valid() always returns false

Comment: Make sure `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is included in your form in your template.

Comment: yes i did that but still the problem exists

Comment: Right above `if form.is_valid():` put `print(form.errors)`. What errors are being shown?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the html form tag?

Comment: Also, the `form.is_valid()` is expecting the `name` of the form to be as `image`.